# How do i setup a callback function for a standard Windows DLL in python?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am working on a small Python program to communicate with a digital signal conditioner ([FSU-SSBD from Mantracourt](https://shop.mantracourt.com/us/product/fast-usb-strain-module-fsu-ssbd-a/)). Basically, the module works by reading the input from a connected strain gauge and streaming it out constantly to the connected computer at 4800 Hz.

But can also be operated directly (without the dedicated software toolkit) using simple commands following ASCII protocol. This is what I am chasing because I need a much lower rate than 4800 Hz, and I need to log data way longer than the 30-minute limit when exporting data captured by the toolkit. But - spoiler alert - it does not work for me.

The module is NOT setup to be assigned a COM port for communication, so this is not an option. Instead, Mantracourt provides a DLL Driver along with some [documentation](https://www.mantracourt.com/userfiles/software/fsudrvxx_dll_driver_setup.exe), but I can't seem to get it right in my program.

MY PROGRAM (minimal working example):

```
import ctypes

class DLLCommunicator:

    @ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_float)
    def callback(station,value):
        print(f"Station: {station}, Value: {value}")

    def testDLL(self):
        DLLpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FSUDrvXX DLL Driver\FSUDrv64.dll"
        FSUDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(DLLpath)
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE(self.callback)
        res1 = FSUDLL.OPENPORT()
        print(f"OpenPort: {res1}")
        res2 = FSUDLL.DEVICECOUNT()
        print(f"DeviceCount: {res2}")
        FSUDLL.COMMANDMODE()
        res3 = FSUDLL.READCOMMAND("OVAL")
        print(f"OVAL: {res3}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DLLTest = DLLCommunicator()
    DLLTest.testDLL()
```

As you can see in the code, the first step is to INITIALISE() the DLL and proviude a callback address to receive the output from the DLL commands. Then the function OPENPORT() is called to open up the FSU-SSBD interface for communication. Then i call COMMANDMODE() to switch the FSU-SSBD from its default state of streaming live data at 4800 Hz and to command mode, where I should then be able to read/write different ASCII-commands like "OVAL", which reads a single value from the module.

When run, the above code produces the following output:

```
OpenPort: -500 #("Cannot list USB Devices. Problem with USB bus.")
DeviceCount: 1 #("A long value indicating the number of detected FSU Modules", 1 is correct) 
OVAL: -200 #("Error during read or write.")
```

If I run my program when the FSU-SSBD is disconnected, I get the following output instead:

```
OpenPort: -600 #("The calibration information cannot be retrieved so streamed values may be  incorrect.")
DeviceCount: 0 #("A long value indicating the number of detected FSU modules", 0 is now correct)
OVAL: -200 #("Error during read or write.")
```

The way I see it I can clearly make contact with the module as it understands and responds to my DLL function calls and knows whether the module is connected or not. This makes me think that there is something wrong with how I am trying to setup my callback function.

As an added issue or bonus info, the program crashes after the last print statement. I don't know why.

I know that this is difficult (if not impossible) to replicate without having an actual FSU-SSBD module ready at hand. But I am hoping that someone experienced in ctypes and DLL communication with Python can find the time to look at the DLL documentation and spot where my code breaks. There is some Example Declarations for VBA, PureBasic and C at the end of the document.

Thank you for reading along!

---

UPDATED MWE:

*Updated based on @Mark Tolonens comments*

```
import ctypes

class DLLCommunicator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DLLpath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FSUDrvXX DLL Driver\FSUDrv64.dll'
        self.CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.c_float)
        self.cb = self.CALLBACK(self.callback)  # Wrap the bound method and save it as an attribute.
        self.station = ""
        self.value = ""

    def callback(self, station, value):
        self.station = station
        self.value = value

    def testDLL(self):
        self.fsuDll = ctypes.WinDLL(self.DLLpath)
        fsuInitialise = self.fsuDll.INITIALISE
        fsuInitialise.argtypes = self.CALLBACK,  # Recommended so ctypes can typecheck parameters
        fsuInitialise.restype = None            # Declares return type.     
        fsuInitialise(self.cb)

        self.openPort = self.fsuDll.OPENPORT
        self.openPort.argtypes = None
        self.openPort.restype = ctypes.c_long
        res1 = self.openPort()
        print(f"OpenPort: {res1}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DLLTest = DLLCommunicator()
    DLLTest.testDLL()
```

Output of prin statement in self.testDLL() is still -500, meaning "Cannot list USB devices. Problem with USB bus."

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate a class method with `CFUNCTYPE` if it is decorated with `@staticmethod` so it won't required `self`.

Using methods on a class *instance* is tricky.  The *bound* method needs to be wrapped in a (CFUNCTYPE) instance and that instance must be saved during the lifetime the callback is used.

The below DLL code was used for testing that the callback was passed correctly:

**test.c** (Microsoft compiler command: cl /LD test.c)

```c
#define API __declspec(dllexport)  // Windows requirement for function export.

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(int, float);

void API INITIALISE(CALLBACK cb) {
    cb(123, 4.56f);
}
```

Below works and allows access to the class instance (`self`) by the callback:

```py
import ctypes

CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float)

class DLLCommunicator:

    def callback(self, station, value):
        print(f'Station: {station}, Value: {value}')

    def testDLL(self):
        DLLpath = './test.dll'
        FSUDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(DLLpath)
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE.argtypes = CALLBACK,  # Recommended so ctypes can typecheck parameters
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE.restype = None        # Declares return type.
        # Wrap the bound method and save it as an attribute.
        self.cb = CALLBACK(self.callback)
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE(self.cb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DLLTest = DLLCommunicator()
    DLLTest.testDLL()
```

Output:

```
Station: 123, Value: 4.559999942779541
```

Below also works if `self` access isn't required:

```py
import ctypes

CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_float)

class DLLCommunicator:

    @CALLBACK      # decorator order matters!
    @staticmethod
    def callback(station, value):
        print(f'Station: {station}, Value: {value}')

    def testDLL(self):
        DLLpath = './test.dll'
        FSUDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(DLLpath)
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE.argtypes = CALLBACK,  # Recommended so ctypes can typecheck parameters
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE.restype = None        # Declares return type.
        FSUDLL.INITIALISE(self.callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DLLTest = DLLCommunicator()
    DLLTest.testDLL()
```

(same output)

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, my two issues remain when running your code against the DLL:

1) My calls keep returning the value indicating an error (output description in the post)

2) After running your exact code I still experience the crash at the end - a possible duplicate of [THIS SO-article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66157391/accessing-a-dll-with-ctypes-crashes-python-exe) where you mention string buffers. Could that somehow be a solution in my case? And/Or do I need to explicitly declare restype and argtypes for each of the individual functions used, as with the INITIALISE-function?

Comment: @NikolajSodemann Yes, correctly setting argtypes and restype are key to using ctypes correctly, and using writable buffers via create_string_buffer when necessary, too. If you still have issues, provide the C function prototypes if you need help calling some of them.

Comment: Another example: READCOMMAND probably takes a c_char_p, so setting argtypes to that will error with “OVAL” (a Unicode string) and should be b”OVAL” (a byte string).

Comment: I have added an updated MWE to the question,  where I try to include argtypes and restype (same result). As I currently (mis)understand it, the callback function catches a byte and a float for Python to store in a variable (like writing the float Value to self.value in callback()). Is this wrong? Here is a few function prototypes from the DLL documentation PDF:

`void __stdcall INITIALISE(*CallbackAddress);
long __stdcall OPENPORT(void);
void __stdcall COMMANDMODE(void);
long __stdcall READCOMMAND(char *Command, float *Result);
long __stdcall WRITECOMMAND(char *Command, float Value);`

Comment: Here's what doc says about the INITIALISE function:

INITIALISE
Initialise DLL and setup callback address so that when data is streamed the hosting application receives a callback.
`void __stdcall IINITIALISE(*iCallbackAddress);
#iCallbackAddress is a long pointer to the address of the callback procedure`
Required before OPENPORT is called. Pass the address of the callback function which must have the following format:
`Procedure CallBackProc(byte Station, float Value)`
As this callback operated at 4800 times per second it is important to keep your code brief in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import ctypes

# This class provides an interface to a Mantracourt FSU-SSBD module via a DLL provided by Mantracourt.
# The FSU-SSBD is a digital signal conditioner that streams data at 4800 Hz.
# It can also be operated with simple ASCII commands, allowing for data logging at a lower rate than 4800 Hz.
class DLLCommunicator:
    def __init__(self):
        # DLL provided by Mantracourt
        self.DLLpath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FSUDrvXX DLL Driver\FSUDrv64.dll'
        self.FSUDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(self.DLLpath)

        # The callback function type expected by the DLL
        # This function will be called by the DLL with two arguments: a station (byte) and a value (float)
        self.callback_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.c_float)
        self.callback = self.callback_type(self.callback_fn)

        # Setup the function prototypes from the DLL
        self.INITIALISE = self.FSUDLL.INITIALISE
        self.INITIALISE.argtypes = [self.callback_type]
        self.INITIALISE.restype = None

        # Rest of the DLL methods defined in similar manner...
        # ...

    # This function will be called by the DLL with two arguments: a station (byte) and a value (float)
    def callback_fn(self, station, value):
        print(f"Station: {station}, Value: {value}")

    # Test method to initialize and use the DLL functions
    def testDLL(self):
        self.INITIALISE(self.callback)

        # Calling DLL functions and printing returned results
        res1 = self.OPENPORT()
        print(f"OpenPort: {res1}")

        res2 = self.DEVICECOUNT()
        print(f"DeviceCount: {res2}")

        self.COMMANDMODE()

        # Reading a value from the module using the READCOMMAND function
        result = ctypes.c_float()
        res3 = self.READCOMMAND("OVAL".encode('utf-8'), ctypes.byref(result))
        print(f"OVAL: {res3}")

# Instantiate the DLLCommunicator and call the testDLL method
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DLLTest = DLLCommunicator()
    DLLTest.testDLL()
```

Please note that it's not possible for us to test this code without having an actual FSU-SSBD module, as the DLL and the module interact with each other. Since the DLL functions rely on a physical device to operate properly, any attempt to call them without the device present will likely result in errors.

We've ordered an actual FSU-SSBD unit which will be arriving in a week. Once we have the unit, we will be able to run this code and test its functionality. Please stay tuned for updates as we work to get this module up and running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).